# Pandas: if row in column A contains strings “x”,"y","z", write “ “x_”,"y_","z_" to row in column B

Tags: python, string, pandas

For pandas, I'm looking for a way to write conditional values to each row in column B, based on substrings for corresponding rows in column A.

So if cell in A contains "WMEAS", write "MEASURED" to B. Or if cell in A contains "WRES", write "Residue" to B,  Or if cell in A contains "WPRES", write "Percentage" to B,

I tried using str.contains method with map .As I mentioned, with Map I can do with two variables which is true, false but not for all the four.

````
create_table['Field_Type'] = create_table ['Field_Type'].map({True: 'Measured', False: 'Estimated'})```


Desired Output :


Field_Name    Field_Type
WMEAS_LD(1)   Measured
RMEAS_LD(1)    Measured
W_LD(1)        Estimated
WPRES_LN(1)    Percentage
WRES_UN(1)      Residual.


[![This is how dataset look like][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaRQm.png
````

Answer (score 0):

You can iteratively look for all combinations you need

```
def apply_func(col_a):
    if "WMEAS" in col_a:
        result = "MEASURED"
    elif "WRES" in col_a:
        result = "Residue"
    elif "WPRES" in col_a:
        result = "Percentage"
    else:
        result = ""
    return result

df['B'] = df['A'].astype(str).apply(apply_func)
```

Comment: argument of type 'float' is not iterable. I got this error

Comment: can you post a sample of your data? if you have mixed type column, first cast it to string type `df['B'] = df['A'].astype(str).apply(apply_func)`. I have updated the code sample.

Comment: instead of WMEAS, We can also have VMEAS, RMEAS and something like that as well

Comment: Then you can match by `MEAS` or `MEAS_`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the columns of 'A' and then set values of 'B' using df.at[]

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     if(df.at[index,'A'] == "WMEAS"):
          df.at[index,'B'] = "Measured"
     elif other conditions  
          and operations
```